# Mysterious 1HRA 6-pin chip

Tags: identification

I'm trying to fix a dead Chinese vacuum cleaner (Alfawise FJ166) and have identified all components except this small 6-pin chip. It has marking `1HRA` and weird symbol I was unable to identify.

It should be some sort of power regulator for MCU as battery pack is ~22V and no other IC is related to voltage regulation.

[image: component and surroundings]

Comment: Have you, by any chance, traced out a schematic around it? It's very likely a buck converter controller of some sort (likely with an internal switch), given the inductor and large diode nearby. (I assume buck converter because a 22 V battery voltage would need to be stepped down to run logic, and it looks far too small to run a motor). If you can trace out the schematic, it would be pretty simple to figure out what exactly the chip is doing, and even if we can't find a part number for it it may be possible to replace it with an equivalent.

Comment: I was able to figure out the logo - it's MicrOne and their buck converters in that packages do match at least some pins - ME3116 seems to be one of them.

Comment: A switch mode regulator for sure.

Answer (score 1):

For 99% it is step-down DC/DC converter by MicrOne, likely similar to ME3116 or MEI3001 as pinout and connected components (especially inductor and bootstrap capacitor) seem to match.

This page was a hint for rare logo - https://iclogos.cuvoodoo.info